# POST and GET works in Postmen but PUT and DELETE doesn't

Tags: php, api, postman, rect

i'm trying a simple Rest api the GET and POST methods works but then when i try to test the PUT and DELETE `Undefined Index` errors show and ofc the database doesn't get updated, i tried inputing the data through `form-data` and `raw` ass well as `x-www-form-urlencoded` but yeah nothing 
when I input manually the data into my code instead of `$_REQUEST` it works just fine
here's my  code :

```
<?php 
try{
    include 'connection.php';
    $method_name=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])
    {

        switch ($method_name) 
        {
          case 'GET':
            $qry="SELECT * from product";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $temp_cat[]=array("product_id"=>$row[0],"product_name"=>$row[1],"product_price"=>$row[2],"product_qty"=>$row[3]);
            }

            $data=array("status"=>"1","message"=>"success","result"=>$temp_cat);
            break;

          case 'POST':

            $name=$_REQUEST['product_name'];
            $price=$_REQUEST['product_price'];
            $qty=$_REQUEST['product_qty'];
            $qry="INSERT INTO product(product_name,product_price,product_qty) values('$name','$price','$qty')";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $qry))
            {
                $data=array("status"=>"1","message"=>"success","result"=>"Product add successfully");
            }
            else{
                $data=array("status"=>"1","message"=>"success","result"=>"Something wrong!!!");
            }
            break;

          case 'PUT':
            $id=$_REQUEST['product_id'];
            $name=$_REQUEST['product_name'];
            $price=$_REQUEST['product_price'];
            $qty=$_REQUEST['product_qty'];
            $qry="UPDATE product SET product_name='".$name."', product_price='".$price."',product_qty='".$qty."' where product_id='".$id."' ";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $qry))
            {
                $data=array("status"=>"1","message"=>"success","result"=>"Product Update successfully");
            }
            else{
                $data=array("status"=>"1","message"=>"success","result"=>"Something wrong!!!");
            }
            break;

          case 'DELETE':
            $id=$_REQUEST['product_id'];
            $qry="delete from product where product_id='".$id."'";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $qry))
            {
                $data=array("status"=>"1","message"=>"success","result"=>"Product Update successfully");
            }
            else{
                $data=array("status"=>"1","message"=>"success","result"=>"Something wrong!!!");
            }
            break;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else{
        $data=array("status"=>"0","message"=>"Please enter proper request method !! ");
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

}
catch(Exception $e) {
     echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}


?>
```

[this is a screenshot of postman while trying DELETE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGRPq.jpg)

bear in mind i'm new to this and this is literally my first time working with this !

Comment: You shouldn't use `$_REQUEST` but instead use `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_PUT` and `$_GET` again for `DELETE`.

Comment: @Nicolas — There is no `$_PUT` super global

Comment: Is it better to use `$_REQUEST` then ? @Quentin

Comment: @Nicolas — No, `$_REQUEST` should be avoided completely because its a mash up on `$_POST`, `$_GET`, and `$_COOKIES` and you rarely want data to com from any of the three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of PUT and DELETE you need to get the request parameters this way:

```
$requestParams = array();
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $requestParams);
```

Then you can access the values like using $_GET or $_POST:

```
$requestParams['product_id']
```

Hope this helps.